# Div id passing to a java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my html page.

```
<div>
    <div id="defaultcard" class="container">
        <div id="imgspace1" class="container">
            <input id="edit" type="button" name="answer" value="Edit" onclick="showDiv()" />
            <input id="cancel" type="button" name="answer" value="Cancel" onclick="showBtn()" />
            <div id="image_preview">
                <img id="previewing" src="" />
            </div>                    
        </div>
        <div id="imgspace2" class="container">                
            <input id="edit" type="button" name="answer" value="Edit" onclick="showDiv()" />
            <div id="image_preview">
                <img id="previewing1" src="" />
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div id="imgspace3" class="container">

        </div>
        <div id="imgspace4" class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my js file(image preview part only).

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) 
{
    $("#file").css("color","green");
    $('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
    $('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('#previewing').attr('width', '100%');
    $('#previewing').attr('height', '100%');
};
});
```

how can i upload different images to each `div`. i want know how to pass that `div` id to this js file.

Comment: please explain clearly...

Comment: You have more than one entity with the same id,  `id="image_preview"` thats not legal in the same page and will confuse ant javascript you write.

Comment: Do you want to pass the preview image, into one of the 4 "imgspace" divs?

Comment: If you want to get ids of all divs under your defaultcard div, you can make this: var array; $('#defaultcard > div').each(function(){
      array.push($(this).attr('id')); 
    });